# Scaling Java apps in Fedora 31

Tags: java, linux, scale, fedora, hidpi

so I spent days looking through the internet but couldn't solve my problem. I recently installed Fedora 31 on my Matebook X Pro (3000 x 2000 resolution), and my GUI was tiny. So I could scale my GUI in the settings to 200% and everything works perfectly, except for my own Java apps. They are really tiny, I can't even read the fonts. Any ideas on how to scale them (all together?) without having to change their code?

Appreciate all ideas

Comment: If you're asking for a solution that doesn't involve changing your application, it's probably off-topic :/

Comment: I mean I could make my app autoresizing, but I have no clue on how to do so...

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/526484/fix-scaling-of-java-based-applications-for-a-high-dpi-screen

Answer (score 0):

It might work with setting the system to use large fonts.

Swing and JavaFX can code a **scaling**, and enlarge the **application bounds** by say a factor 1.75. Whether that repairs everything I do not know.

Scaling probably is needed when you worked in pixels. Otherwise setting a **larger font** would help. If buttons and such are small, and no pixel bounds are set, you could try a **system LookAndFeel** (UIManager).

Swing content pane:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    final double scale = 2.0;
    g2.scale(scale, scale);
    super.paint(g);
    g2.scale(1/scale, 1/scale);
}
```